# React won't load page "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm going through this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-web-api-minimal-spa/5-exercise-create-api

It works until I get to this step:
Add a proxy by opening up package.json and the following entry:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Now when I rerun `yarn start` the same page doesn't render on http://localhost:5000, but if I remove that proxy line from the package.json it still renders on http://localhost:3000.

I see these errors in the console:

```
manifest.json:1          GET http://localhost:5000/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
The attempt to bind "/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" in the workspace failed as this URI is malformed.
```

And in the html I see:

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
```

When I remove the proxy entry in the package.json I also get this in html after:

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root">
  <div class="App">
    <div>No pizzas</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pizza-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "styled-components": "^5"
  }
}
```

And my Main.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const PizzaFrame = styled.div`
    border: solid 1px gray;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px grey;
    font-family: Arial;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
`;

const Title = styled(Input)`
    text-transform: uppercase;
`;

const Save = styled.button`
   width: 100px;
   margin: 10px;
   background: green;
   color: white;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
`;

const Pizza = ({ pizza }) => {
   const [data, setData] = useState(pizza);
   const [dirty, setDirty] = useState(false);

   function update(value, fieldName, obj) {
   setData({ ...obj, [fieldName] : value });
   setDirty(true);
   }

   function onSave() {
   setDirty(false);
   // make REST call
   }

   return (<React.Fragment>
     <PizzaFrame>
     <h3>
       <Title onChange={(evt) => update(evt.target.value, 'name', data)} value={data.name} /> 
     </h3>
     <div>
       <Input onChange={(evt) => update(evt.target.value, 'description', data)} value={data.description} />
     </div>
     {dirty ? 
      <div><Save onClick={onSave}>Save</Save></div> : null
     }
    </PizzaFrame>
    </React.Fragment>)
}

const Main = () => {
  const [pizzas, setPizzas] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  function fetchData() {
    fetch("/api/pizza")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setPizzas(data))
  }

  const data = pizzas.map(pizza => <Pizza pizza={pizza} />)

  return (<React.Fragment>
    {pizzas.length === 0 ?
    <div>No pizzas</div> :
    <div>{data}</div>
    }
  </React.Fragment>)
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: _"page doesn't render on http://localhost:5000"_... you're not meant to open that URL in your browser

Answer (score 1):

The value in `proxy` is meant to be the server, which should provide the data, which the react application is fetching. Therefore, this server needs to be started as well (step 4 in your tutorial).

- `localhost:3000` serves the react app (the frontend)
- `localhost:5000` serves the backend (the mock server)

The react development tools provides the proxy mechanism as a help. When the `proxy` is set, you can call it by a URL without hostname. i.e. `/api/pizza`.

When you exchange your backend API mock with the real implementation, you need to change this to whatever port you service is running at (5059 in your tutorial).

Comment: That server is started yes, using ```npx json-server --watch --port 5000 db.json``` . The tutorial says "Your app should start as normal on http://localhost:5000." SO what should I be saying at 5000 now? I have a db.json in the main project folder, and in the src folder, I didn't know where it was supposed to go.

Comment: Did you just managed to solved this? I got same error.

Comment: _"The tutorial says..."_ it does not say that anywhere @Mitch